# Max out a table height, and include a scroll bar when reached in JavaScript/React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this table:

```
      <Table striped bordered hover align="right" height="200px" width="200px" border="1px solid #000000" className='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="text">Last Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td className="text">{this.state.myArray.join(", ")}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
```

the file is importing my css file, styles.scss:

```
.table {
    maxHeight: '200px';
    overflowY: auto;
}
```

I found instructions to add this in .css to max out the height and when the height is reached, start a scroll bar, but it's not working. Does this work with a SCSS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `.table` tag in your CSS page, make sure that `display: block`. The scroll should work then.

The full CSS:

```
.table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It is locking the box, but instead of scrolling, it just keeps adding things below the box

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "keeps adding things below the box"? Obviously we dont have your 'Table' element that you imported but with the normal html 'table', this should work. Would it be possible for you perhap include the 'Table' page

Comment: I got it by adding overflow: scroll;